# How do I remove everything before " - "?

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to remove the text (in this example, it's "Hi - "). But it's not working.

```
<div class="custom-card-title">
  <!-- Change to 1-1/32 HELLO  -->
  <a href="#">Hi - 1-1/32 HELLO</a>
</div>
```

```
let name = $('.custom-card-title a').text();
const newName = name.split(" - ").pop();
name = `${newName}`
```

Comment: This code is removing the `Hi` part correctly. Do you want to update the text in anchor tag with the newName (in this case `1-1/32 HELLO`) ?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, updating the text in anchor tag with only "1-1/32 HELLO" @melvin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.html()` or `.text()` here to set the contents of an anchor element.

```
let name = $('.custom-card-title a').text();
const newName = name.split("-").pop();
name.text(newName) // or name.html(newName)
```

`html()` is used to return or change the inner html and text content of selected elements. `text()` is used to return or change the text content of selected elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.html()` function to append the modified text to the anchor tag.

```
let name = $('.custom-card-title a');
const newName = name.text().split(" - ").pop();
name.html(newName);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let name = $('.custom-card-title a').text();
const newName = name.split("Hi - ")[1];
name = `${newName}`
```